# Worklight does not rebuild javascript/html when deploying to Android Simulator

Tags: android, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

My worklight is working fine in the Android simulator. As per the documentation, I have two projects listed in Eclipse: The base worklight app and the Environment-specific Android project that was automatically built.

The problem is that when I change anything on the javascript side or my index.html and then click the Android-specific project using "Run As" => "Android Application", none of the changes in the parent project actually get propogated to the Android project.

Only if I select the parent project and then select "Run As" => "Run on Worklight Development Server", followed by the previous action do the actual JS/html changes actually get reflected in the Android simulator.

Why do I have to do these two steps? Why doesn't just re-deploying the APK automatically cause the parent project to be rebuilt in a single step?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated Android project is just that - generated.
The generated Android project is a mirror of the android\native folder, It's a "copy".

In order to update this "copy", you must build your project. It is an explicit action you must do and is by design.

Additionally, I don't see the two steps that you mention.

1. You write some code.
2. There must be at least 1 initial deployment to the server
3. You can now preview your app in the Worklight Console
4. You can do additional changes, refresh the browser and you will see your  changes w/out additional re-builds & re-dpeloyments
5. You now want to see your changes in your actual app

Because the generated native project is a separate "copy" of your app, you must re-build in order to get these changes into the actual app.

Comment: Well, that's silly. I have a cordova plugin which simply cannot be previewed in the server. Deploying to the server is not a helpful step.

Thus, if I have changed the javascript and simply want to preview in Android directly - it seems there should be a simple one-shot way of acheiving this.

Surely this is not an abnormal workflow?

Comment: You are correct in saying that Cordova plug-ins cannot be previewed "in the server" - Cordova plug-ins are native code and Worklight Console cannot preview that for you; in order to see the result of your Cordova plug-in you must run your app in either the Android Emulator or a physical device. What you could do instead is work directly on the generated Android project and once satisfied copy back to the Worklight project your Java and JavaScript code; this of course means you will lose the instant preview capability; it is a trade-off.

Comment: There is nothing that can be "instant" regarding copying your code into the generated Android project, it is an actual Android project. It must be *compiled* (unlike web resources such as JS, HTML and CSS, images etc). Now imagine you press ctrl+s every other second, do you really want your Android project to be auto-compiled every second? Your computer will not appreciate you. :-)

Comment: That said, if you'd like to submit a feature request, you can do so in the following link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/ -- my personal opinion is that this is not useful given the nature of things.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. (Yes, actually - an auto-compile or auto-build option only upon "Run As" => "Android...." would be quite nice). Will definitely fill out a feature request =).

Comment: Does not guarantee anything, of course... good luck! If your question has been "resolved", please mark as Answered.